# Access VBA: No current record

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my Access DB, I have set a VBA code that looks for a record that has a certain value in the field called `FieldB`. If the record is present, the variable `Var` takes the value of the field `FieldA`, otherwise a default value of `100`.

The code I wrote is the following. The problem is that, when the record is not present, I get the error `No current record` at the command `IsNull(VESRecordSet.Fields(0).Value)`. I suppose that there are some mistakes in this code and that it can be written in a better way.

```
sql = " SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE FieldB = 'current_value');"
Set VESRecordSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)

If IsNull(VESRecordSet.Fields(0).Value) Then
    Var = VESRecordSet.Fields(0).Value
Else
    Var = "100"
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.EOF` to detect if there's a record. That's true if the recordset is at the end of the file (there are no records left), and if it's at the end of the file when you've just opened it, it contains no records.

```
If Not VESRecordSet.EOF Then
    Var = VESRecordSet.Fields(0).Value
Else
    Var = "100"
End If
```